# ISP Replaces SSL Certificates... Any Solution?

Tags: internet, browser, ssl, internet-connection, certificate

My ISP uses a software that replaces site certificates with it own certificate so secure pages are always untrusted. Is there any solution for this? Is it safe to proceed with the resulting sites (including gmail)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, proceeding is not safe; your ISP is performing a man-in-the-middle attack on your encrypted traffic, and can therefore read all traffic if they choose so.

> Is there any solution for this

Yes: Get a new ISP.

As a side note:

I am very surprised; I have never heard of an ISP doing this, and I would not even consider such a company a proper ISP (since they don't provide the service of an ISP, which is sending and receiving the data that *you* send or want to receive).

What ISP is this? I can't imagine any regular ISP doing this.

Comment: I'm shocked as well, that's an incredible security vulnerability. I would contact your ISP **immediately**. It could be someone in between you and the site pretending to be your ISP.

Comment: So, aren't there any workaround for this? e.g. saving the good site certificate to a file and force using them ...etc?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  You might be able to find some loophole where they don't filter all of the traffic, or you might be able to set up some sort of VPN to provide a path outside of the network (which is just another kind of loophole), but if they're at all clever and serious about this behavior the answer is no.

Comment: The name!  What's the name man! The name of the ISP?!

Comment: In Iran, it's quite common to prevent access to the internet after a subscription ends. Names? ParsOnline, HiWeb, so on ... . And yes, they can sniff data if someone ignored warning unknowingly!

Answer (score 1):

Get new ISP ok.
But i get simple solution, use VPN.
My ISP block site by injectng (replacing) SSL certificate, even with DoH/DoT.
So i use VPN to bypass it.